# 'libmtp error: unknown error' while opening files on android internal storage

Tags: 13.10, usb, android, mtp

I connect my Android phone to Ubuntu 13.10 through USB to access to its internal storage.

Whenever I try to open a file directly from the phone memory, it displays an error saying that the file couldn't be loaded with this error message:

> libmtp error: unknown error.

But when I copy and paste the same file to my PC, I can open it.

For instance, with an image:

[image: could not load image '<filename>' libmtp error: unknown error.]

What could be the problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? Make sure you are running an up-to-date version of Ubuntu and report back. Thanks!

Comment: It's the first result when searching this error. It would be good to have a lead to a solution here. I still get this error in March 2016 with up to date software.